# Database in the cloud?

Tags: database, performance, cloud-computing

Some of my recent clients are asking for remote connections to the office server, for standalone work, etc, in winForm applications.

Since the concept of the web is remote connection to a server both of data and resources, it should be possible to place both of this in cloud and have the winForm apps connect to it as if web Apps.

As any one tested this, is working like this?

Is it fast enough?

Is it secure?

What is the best cloud host for this type of work ?

Comment: I think I'm going to post this every time someone says 'Cloud': http://www.dilbert.com/strips/comic/2011-01-07/

Comment: How dare you insult THE cloud, the cloud punishes those puny weaklings who try to insult THE cloud.

Comment: Someone's been sucked into jargin. You can do this with any of the free databases and a language capable of programming a web service.

Comment: Has anyone tested remotely accessing an application over the Internet? I'd say yes. Ever heard of web sites?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? especially without a reason. Reupvoting to balance. Just because it's not a super new question doesn't mean it's not valid.

Comment: @Mercfh: I was the downvoter - and I did so because the question completely lacks insight, research and experience while propagating uninformed use of buzzwords. I wasn't going to openly hate on the OP, but now that you've asked... I guess I have to be the bad guy.

Comment: I was wondering if the OP got to more information since the question was posted since I am considering a somewhat similar scenario. Thx for the update if you got any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Architecturally there is nothing to prevent you from building this.  I would, however, recommend building a web service (or WCF app) for your Winform app to call instead of directly calling the database from the app.

We've had a lot of success building MS Click-Once smart clients that do exactly that.  Separating out the code that calls to the DB isolates your Winform app from having to know what SQL to use.  Additionally, if at somepoint down the road the business requirements change and you need to build a web app instead (or in addition to) the Winform app, your new web app can call the same web service and be up and running that much quicker.

Comment: +1: It's a safe bet to use that architecture even if you're only planning for LAN deployment. It's easily developed, easily secured, has the opportunity to scale well, and supports internet deployment.

Comment: @SnOrfus - my thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind.  I recently attended Azure training and as was pointed out by the instructor **some** countries legally require you to keep your database on-site.  You can host your application in the cloud, but the database has to reside on company grounds.

That said I'm not sure what the cloud gets you that hosing the web site/service on-site doesn't.  Nothing that you've posted so far indicates to me that the cloud is the appropriate decision.  What are your needs?  Remote access can just as easily be done on-site.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes and no**

Firstly you need to define what you mean by "In the cloud";

Putting aside that issue.

There should be now problems what so ever.

I had one project (Winform) that runs in this manner.

i.e. Fat client (Winform) with a public facing SQL server.

It works well, however the only downside is the client(s) require an internet connection.

Unless you plan to have some kind of redundancy built into the application eg local database that holds transactions until a connection can be made, upon which the transactions are merged.

Comment: There is one (1) problem: how do you secure the sucker?  This is the very problem that plagues distributed applications.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the office network with a VPN. No need to rebuild the winforms app assuming they can connect to the database (network admins love to deal with this kind of stuff).

If you wanted clients or business partners/non employees to connect, that's another issue.